# Why won't String.format() give me a left zero-padded floating point output?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm trying to get the decimal `8.6` to render to a left zero-padded string i.e. `08.6`.

Why doesn't the following seem to work?

```
double number = 8.6;
String.format("%03.1f", number); //expect "08.6", get "8.6"
```

The formatting string seems to be correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect four when you write three?

Comment: Because I didn't know the decimal *point* counted towards the width. Thanks for the wit, very helpful. /s

Comment: Well, a point is tiny, and it can be easily overlooked ;-) And "width" really *is* the width: integral part, decimal point, fractional digits (!) and even the sign, if negative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *is* giving you a left zero-padded floating point output, it's just that the field width of `3` *includes* the decimal point and the fractional portion (and the sign, if it's negative), so you need to use `%04.1f` instead for that particular value.

The output of:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double number = 8.6;
        System.out.println(String.format("%04.1f", number));
    }
}
```

is:

```
08.6
```

Comment: And it includes all fractional digits!

Comment: I should've realized that the point counts towards the width. Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give as `%04.1f` to get the output as `08.6`.